# SofMax Pro 6 test for parallel curves

Tags: formula, curve-fitting

I'm already successfully using the SoftMax Pro formula system and curve fit feature to analyze my data. Now I want to go one step further and identify parallel curves. Is anyone able to recommend a good way of approaching this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a great white paper published by Molecular Devices related to this topic.  I suggest you read through it.  http://www.softmaxpro.com/protocol/show/70

In summary you want to apply 4 parameter curvefit to 2 data sets.

y=D+((A-D)/(1+(x/C)^B))

A for curve fit 1 (lets call it A1) and curve fit 2 (A2) should be close to each other.
Same goes with B variable.
C can vary.

Apply Fieller's theorem equation (lets call it Var(x)) to the ratios A1/A2 and B1/B2.
Var(a/b) is a formula to calculate confidence interval for the ratio of two means. See 
[Fieller's Theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fieller's_theorem)!

For example, using alpha=0.1 the output should not exceed the range 0.9 < Var(A1/A2) < 1.1 (same for Bs).

Note: SoftMax Pro 6.4 offers a built-in parallelism test protocol (located in the Data Analysis folder in the Protocol Library) that is based on Fieller’s theorem.  It is the method recommended by the USDA.

Comment: It's good practice to leave some kind of summary answer in case the link goes offline. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer